# Question encouraging list type answers?

Tags: discussion

[Is there any music with no meter?](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/50052/is-there-any-music-with-no-meter)

I was just reading this question. The answers are all listing a single genre that fits the criteria (meterless, or mostly meterless, music).   I know that list-type questions are generally discouraged, but I feel like this one is better than a list of resources because it's static music genres, and more stable than resources. On the other hand, it's still just a list of things for the reader to follow up on.

Should something like this be allowed, or closed?

Answer (score 3):

One of the primary reasons this kind of question is disallowed is because relative voting is meaningless.  One example is as good as another, so it turns into a popularity contest at the start and then devolves into the ones that were upvoted early just getting more votes while the others are ignored because they're buried.

There is also the question of whether we want to cultivate things that are just a pile of one-word answers.  Though a couple on that question are more in-depth, it had to be protected because of multiple low quality answer.

I personally do not feel that this question contributes much value, particularly from the perspective of a musician.

Answer (score -1):

I think stack exchange deals pretty well with *some* list-type questions.

If I can pick up on Matthew's points:

> relative voting is meaningless. One example is as good as another.

I don't see how that's necessarily true. Each item may not be subjectively as good as the next; there's the possibility of 'list items' that are seen as more interesting or relevant getting voted higher.

You could certainly argue that the idea of 'accepted answer' is meaningless when many very different answers might be 'right' - but there's already the possibility of a question having more than one right answer in non-list type questions.

> the ones that were upvoted early just getting more votes while the others are ignored because they're buried.

I agree that is a problem - but I think it's a general problem with SE, not limited to any type of question.

> There is also the question of whether we want to cultivate things that are just a pile of one-word answers. Though a couple on that question are more in-depth, it had to be protected because of multiple low quality answer.

Possibly that's a general problem with popular questions, which this one was.