# Constant downvotes were due to III+ chord / harmonic minor?

Tags: discussion, support

This question is a continuation from [I am constantly getting downvotes on my posts for no reason](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3178/i-am-constantly-getting-downvotes-on-my-posts-for-no-reason).

---

It looks like my posts like this are receiving unexpected downvotes:

> The diatonic chords are:
>
> In major keys: I, ii, iii, IV, V, vi, vii<sup>o</sup>
>
> In minor keys: i, ii<sup>o</sup>, III<sup>+</sup>, iv, V, VI, <sup>♯</sup>vii<sup>o</sup>

Michael Curtis has sent me this comment:

> "My guess is your CONSTANT listing of the mediant triad in minor as an augmented chord is why you are getting downvotes. Chord matrixes from three minor scales. It misrepresent how minor key harmony works."

User45266's series of comments looked like:

> - "These chords are diatonic to harmonic minor, yes, and that should be noted in the answer."
> - "I think we already had this discussion before, but you seem to be using harmonic minor."
> - As I've said before, *please notate in your answer that you are using harmonic minor*"

Does anyone have suggestions for this, please?

Comment: I'm not an expert, but I'm not sure what is unclear with the comments. AFAIK, there are 3 minor scales (natural, harmonic, melodic). Your answer seems to generalize diatonic chords to *all* minor scales, while the commenters stated that they only apply to *harmonic* minor scale. Now, I don't know who is right/wrong, but could you just clarify in the answer if they apply to *all minor scales*, or only on *harmonic minor scale*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We have had this discussion quite a few times now, both on Meta and in many, many comment threads. [As others](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3179/39614) have [noted before](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3180/39614) in the answer to your previous linked question, when you get downvotes, take a step back and look at how others might see your answer as low-quality. In particular, note that the downvote button provides instruction: "This answer is not useful." Ask yourself how others might see your answer as not useful. Compare your answers with other answers that the community seems to value.

The answers you are asking about are just lists of chords, and more than one person has suggested to you that lists do not constitute useful answers in most cases. [I certainly said this in my answer to another question of yours on Meta.](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3197/39614)

20 answers out of 30 answers of yours that are on the site, i.e., 67% of your answers, are primarily lists, and almost all of those are lists of chords. In most cases, the lists look like padding that really don't have much to do with the original question. Additionally many of these answers have or had at one time misleading or incorrect content, which I and others pointed out to you in the comments. Some of those answers were corrected by you, but once downvotes have been cast, the downvoter may never come back to see if things have changed, or may not be inclined to change their vote. I suspect that most people are reluctant to downvote unless they really dislike an answer, but that once a downvote is cast it takes a better answer to get them to reverse the vote than it would have taken to avoid the downvote in the first place.

You ask: "It looks like my posts like this are receiving unexpected downvotes.... Does anyone have suggestions for this, please?" Take the hint. The downvotes should no longer be unexpected: the community is not enamored of list answers, especially when removing the list leaves little or no content. And try to get the answer right the first time; you can't rely on edits to cause downvoters to reverse their decisions or to attract lots of new upvotes.

Comment: This matches conversations I have had with the OP. Your wording is spot on - these downvotes should now be expected unless behaviour changes.

Comment: Well said; that 20/30 posts being lists statistic was quite eye-opening. And +1 for "expect downvotes"; while they may seem harsh, at this point *(several months, meta posts, explanations, comments, and deletions later)*, they should be no surprise. We seem to be going in circles here with new posts continuing to revive the cycle of community ire and discussion.